# Getting AWS Credentials as configured on POD

Tags: amazon-eks, aws-secrets-manager

**Context:**

1. We are using AWS SM for storing secrets
2. AWS Credentials were loaded from EC2 instance as below

   ```
   public AWSSecretsManager getDefaultSecretsManagerClient(String region) {
        return AWSSecretsManagerClientBuilder.standard()
                .withCredentials(new InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider(false)) // <== Loads credentials from EC2 instance
                .withRegion(region)
                .build();
    }
   ```

**Current:** We are planning to move to Amazon EKS. While running the container the AWS credentials were picked from EC2 instance rather than POD. Can someone please guide me on which credential provider to use here so that AWS creds gets picked up from POD rather than the underlying EC2 instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might look at useing IAM Roles for Service Accounts ([IRSA](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/iam-roles-for-service-accounts.html)) to associate an IAM role with the K8s service account used for the POD. Once you setup IRSA it will behave much like roles for EC2, though you will likely want to use [`DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain.getInstance()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/auth/DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain.html) instead of InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider to retrieve the credentials.

You can also use the [secrets-store-csi-driver-provider-aws](https://github.com/aws/secrets-store-csi-driver-provider-aws) plugin to the CSI secret store driver to retrieve secrets from secrets manager (also using IRSA) as mounted files or etcd secrets. Note that the README for this project also has simplified instructions for setting up IRSA.